# Using an unsigned int in a do-while loop

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, int, do-while

I'm new to coding in c and I've been trying to wrap my head around unsigned integers. This is the code I have:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

     int main(void)
     {
        unsigned int hours;

        do
        {
          printf("Number of hours you spend sleeping a day: ");
          scanf(" %u", &hours);
        }
        while(hours < 0);

        printf("\nYour number is %u", hours);
     }
```

However, when I run the code and use (-1) it does not ask the question again like it should and prints out (Your number is 4294967295) instead. If I change unsigned int to a normal int, the code works fine. Is there a way I can change my code to make the unsigned int work?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Unsigned integers cannot have negative values. That's the point of using unsigned variables: only positive numbers but you get a "greater range" of values (ie. the highest numer is a power of two bigger than the bigger signed integer)

Comment: There are probably ways to do funky casting to make it work, but it's going to be confusing and pretty much pointless. Is there a reason you don't just use an `int`?

Comment: The reason I used unsigned int is because of a question I'm working on which requires me to use it

Comment: mins in undefined variable in while(mins < 0). Not sure how you code runs and prints something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can change my code to make the unsigned int work?

Various approaches possible.

Read as `int` and then convert to `unsigned`.

---

Given "Number of hours you spend sleeping a day: " implies a small legitimate range about  0 to 24, read as `int` and convert.

```
int input;
do {
  puts("Number of hours you spend sleeping a day:");
  if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1) {
    Handle_non_text_input(); // TBD code for non-numeric input like "abc"
  } 
} while (input < 0 || input > 24);
unsigned hours = input;
```

Comment: This goes into a loop when I type a string|char

Comment: @jcarlosweb `Handle_non_text_input();` implies you need to write code to consume the non-numeric text and/or exit the loop.  Perhaps something as simple as `getchar();`.  What is best depends on your goals for non-numeric input.

Answer (score 0):

An unsigned int cannot hold negative numbers. It is useful since it can store a full 32 bit number (twice as large as a regular int), but it cannot hold negative numbers So when you try to *read* your negative unsigned int, it is being read as a positive number. Although both int and unsigned int are 32 bit numbers, they will be *interpreted* much differently.

Comment: So in that case it would not make sense to use unsigned int over a signed int then right?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the next test:

```
do:{
    printf("enter valid input...")
    scanf("new input...")
} while (hours > 24)
```

Why should it work?
An unsigned int in C is a binary number, with 32 bit. that means it's max value is 2^32 - 1.
Note that:

2^32 - 1 == 4294967295. That is no coincidence. Negative ints are usually represented using the "[Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)" method.
A word about that method:

When I use a regular int, it's most significant bit is reserved for sign: 1 if negative, 0 if positive. A positive int than holds a 0 in it's most significant bit, and 1's and 0's on the remaining coordinates in the [ordinary binary manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation).

Negative ints, are represented differently:
Suppose K is a positive number, represented by N bits.
The number (-K) is represented using 1 in the most significant bit, and the  *POSITIVE NUMBER*: (2^(N-1) - K) occupying the N-1 least significant bits.

Example:
Suppose N = 4, K = 7. Binary representation for 7 using 4 bit:
7 = 0111 (The most significant bit is reserved for sign, remember?)

-7 , on the other hand:

-7 = concat(1, 2^(4-1) - 7) == 1001

Another example:

1 = 0001, -1 = 1111.

Note that if we use 32 bits, -1 is 1...1 (altogether we have 32 1's). This is exactly the binary representation of the unsigned int 4294967295. When you use unsigned int, you instruct the compiler to refer to -1 as a positive number. This is where your unexpected "error" comes from.

Now - If you use the while(hours>24), you rule out most of the illegal input. I am not sure though if you rule out all illegal input. It might be possible to think of a negative number such that the compiler interpret it as a non-negative number in the range [0:24] when asked to ignore the sign, and refer to the most significant bit as 'just another bit'.